# Safely check if `this` is null

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior

First of all, I'm aware that calling a method on a null pointer is undefined behavior. I also know that, because this is not supposed to happen, compilers can (and do) assume `this` to always be non-null.

But in real code, you sometimes do it accidentially. Usually, it has no ill effects, except that of course `this` is null in the method, and things may crash.

As a debugging aid, and in the spirit of crash-early, I put `assert(this != 0)` in a method that I accidentially called on null pointers a couple of times before. It seems to work, but clang complains with:

```
warning: 'this' pointer cannot be null in well-defined C++ code; comparison may be
      assumed to always evaluate to true [-Wtautological-undefined-compare]
    assert (this ! = 0);
            ^~~~     ~
```

I wonder what the best (least incorrect) way would be to detect that `this` is null. A simple comparison could be optimized out.

- I could do some pointer arithmetic on `this` to try and fool the compiler, or force it to treat the pointer as an integer.
- I could use `memcmp`.
- Maybe there are compiler-specific extensions to say "don't optimize this expression away"?

One additional concern is that, in case of inheritance, the "null" this pointer might actually be something like `0x00000004`, so it would be nice to also handle that case. I'm interested in a solution for either Clang, MSVC, or GCC.

Comment: "As a debugging aid, and in the spirit of crash-early," you should compile with the various `-fsanitize` options now supported in GCC and clang. You should get the effect of what you were after with your `assert`, without modifying your code. This doesn't answer your actual question, but your actual question, I suspect, doesn't have an answer.

Comment: The standard way in C++ to check a if a pointer is null is myptr == nullptr; I don't know if this is different from NULL or 0, but in any case it's a common check, like after doing dynamic cast to see if it succeeded, so I don't see the compiler should optimise it away, as it's a very important check.

Comment: @TitoneMaurice It makes sense for compilers to optimise away a comparison to `nullptr` when they can prove at compile time that the comparison can never be true. And it's what compilers really do.

Comment: Do note that [`assert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert) is a *macro* that only works if `NDEBUG` is not defined. Most IDE's set `NDEBUG` for release builds, so unless you have comprehensive testing using a debug build using `assert` might not catch all the cases. Also, adding asserts like this to each and every member function is not a good idea IMO. Instead try to add comprehensive unit-testing that can catch these kinds of errors (preferably without the need for `assert`).

Comment: I don't get your question. "this" is only valid within a method and if a method was called, then the object it was called on clearly exists and is not null. So yeah, this is totally equal to assert(true), your compiler is totally right about that. In what strange situation should "this" be able to be null?

Comment: @Aziuth `Foo* f = nullptr; f->member_function();` if `member_function` is not virtual, the member function will (could ?) be called, and `this` would be null.

Comment: @DragonRock Aziuth's point is that this is not valid. It's correct that this is not valid, just missing the point of the question.

Comment: @hvd It's not valid, but I guess it's what happens is OP's program, and it is what OP is trying to detect, am I right ? EDIT : Ok, I understood, sorry for that. `this` is not valid, and thus, could be something else than `nullptr`.

Comment: @DragonRock Ah, just did a test, the method call on a null pointer actually works with my compiler. Huh. Didn't knew that. Would have thought that calling a method on a null pointer results in a runtime error, but yeah, now that I did it, of course, an object is only some data in the memory from the viewpoint of a compiler. My mistake.

Comment: @hvd: A problem with that philosophy is that especially when using multi-threaded code, adding sanitize options is likely to change the interactions between threads such that problems that would arise in its absence don't arise in its presence.  Adding a few individual comparisons here and there would be much less likely to affect intermittent behaviors.

Answer (score 8):

In gcc you can build with `-fsanitize=null`. Clang should have this option as well.

From `man gcc`:

```
       -fsanitize=null
           This option enables pointer checking.  Particularly, the application built with this option turned on will issue an error message when it tries to dereference a NULL pointer, or if a
           reference (possibly an rvalue reference) is bound to a NULL pointer, or if a method is invoked on an object pointed by a NULL pointer.
```

Here is a test program:

```
[ ~]$ cat 40783056.cpp
struct A {
  void f() {}
};

int main() {
  A* a = nullptr;
  a->f();
}
[ ~]$ g++ -fsanitize=null 40783056.cpp
[ ~]$ 
[ ~]$ ./a.out 
40783056.cpp:7:7: runtime error: member call on null pointer of type 'struct A'
```

Comment: Thanks, that feature looks nice, I'll check it out! However, I'm trying to avoid the overhead of explicit null checks - mainly by ensuring I don't have null where I don't expect it. E.g. by having my functions contractually not return null. Also, in my real code I might want to do more than just abort... E.g. print a stacktrace or log something.

Comment: You can use these checks only in unit tests for example. Also they should not take much overhead. As far as I know google uses some of them on production.

Comment: @jdm I see that you speak about clang. Maybe you should check http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html I think it could give stack traces, even though I didn't manage to make it work on my pc. And to me, this feature looks like a dev feature, once you want to have perf, you disable it and you enable optimizations, just like you would NDEBUG (and asserts)

Answer (score 3):

Use `-fno-delete-null-pointer-checks` compiler option to allow this vs null checks.

Comment: Supported by GCC, and Clang version 7 and later. Probably useful if you have legacy code that misuses C++ by intentionally passing null `this` pointers to member functions, instead of using a free function with an explicit arg.  ISO C++ says that's undefined behaviour so compilers can normally assume it doesn't happen, but some large legacy code-bases rely on it.  If not for the standard saying it's UB, it would Just Work in methods on classes with no virtual functions.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, as pointed out by the comments to this question: do try using sanitizers built into the compilers.

To answer your question: you can cast your pointer to `uintptr_t` and compare that value. Please note that this conversion is *implementation defined* and is not guaranteed to work as you expected.

The following code optimizes nothing out with clang 3.9, but removes null pointer check with gcc 7.0. `0x10` has been chosen arbitrarily.

```
struct foo
{
  void bar() {
      if(this == nullptr) {
        sink(__LINE__);
      }
      if((uintptr_t)this < 0x10) {
        sink(__LINE__);
      }
      if((volatile uintptr_t)this < 0x10) {
        sink(__LINE__);
      }
  }
};
```

[demo](https://godbolt.org/g/Dh1h2y)

Comment: I suspect `0x10` should be `sizeof(*this)`

Answer (score 1):

You should check the pointer before calling member function, not after it.

```
Class *object = ...;
...;
if (object) {
  object->...
}
```

Checking whether `this` is nullptr in member function can only introduce calling overhead, and it should always be the caller's duty to ensure that `this` will never be nullptr or dangling or wild pointer.
The same reason for not checking whether rhs is the same as lhs in assignments operator. (But one should make sure that self-assignment works correctly, implementing such operator can be tricky and error-prone)

Trying access member function or variable when `this` is nullptr will generally immediately crash your program, and dereference nullptr is an ub in fact. Having assert(this!=nullptr) when this==nullptr will also immediately terminated your program, but provide more information than crashing, which is also rely on ub.

The first ub checking approach need less effort, and provide less information. The former ub checking approach requires more effort (adding assert everywhere), but does provide more information. Turned out a trade-off?

If the crashing can be reproduced, I would prefer the first one (without assert), one can add some logs and quickly ( O(lgn) ) find out which line crashed the program, and the fact that `this` is `nullptr`. And figuring out which calling is in problem.

If otherwise, then `assert` may provide more information, but does "dereferencing `nullptr`" helps a lot under this situation? I doubt it.

So the right approach, in my opinion, is that build a good logging system, and make it simpler to reproduce the error.

Comment: "The same reason for not checking whether rhs is the same as lhs in assignments operator." -- Huh? For all built-in types and almost all standard library types, given an object `x` of a type that supports assignment, self-assignment (`x = x`) is well-defined and leaves `x` effectively unmodified. It may be reasonably assumed to be well-defined for custom classes as well.

Comment: There may be some misunderstanding. By "not checking", I mean don't put if(lhs == rhs) return lhs; in the first line of assignments operator. But instead of crashing the program, assignments operator should always make sure that lhs==rhs after assignment.

Comment: For many (but not most) implementations of custom assignment operators, if there's no `if (lhs == rhs) return lhs;` at the start of the body, self-assignment leads to bugs, because the implementations often do assume that class invariants on the rhs continue to hold all the way from the start to the end of the body, but class invariants on the lhs may temporarily not hold. If the lhs and the rhs are the same object, breaking the invariants on the lhs means they are broken on the rhs as well. There are other ways to avoid that, but `if (lhs == rhs)` checks are a valid approach too.

Comment: If I knew I or someone on my team is going to *accidentally* call a method on a null pointer, we would just not do that. But that's not how it works... I could try to add a check to every call site, but if I find my program crashes, well then I forgot one. That's why I'm trying to catch this at the method side... What I do now, instead of explicit checks, is trying to ensure I don't get null pointers in the first place. I use references where possible, or define my function contracts such that they shall not return null.

Comment: Do you mean, changes on lhs (free a member pointer or ...) will also affect rhs, when lhs rhs refer to the same object (Common cases in self-assigment)?

Comment: @jdm: Another issue is that object methods may sometimes be called from code one doesn't control.  If one has a .h and an object file for a module, but not the source, it may be difficult to diagnose problems in the module if code that it calls can't honestly determine whether it's receiving null values when it shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your compiler it may aggressively enforce the C++ rule about `this` being a `nullptr` as *undefined* behavior.

However, *optimized* release applications/code need to still be able to gracefully handle and report scenarios where this can occur; and in some cases it may actually be part of an intentional design for optimized performance (JIT engine - such as those I work on).

In that case you need work hand-in-hand with the compiler by clearly informing it of your intentions. A *cast* of any kind on `this` and attempting to compare to any variation of `0` or `nullptr` will **not** be guaranteed work reliably. Typically the compiler will either complain or optimize it away as invalid in *optimized* builds.

Instead, you must HOIST your `nullptr` test out of the `this` *member-function* inlining optimizations. To do that you provide a static (non-member) function that is **not** subject to inlining in order to perform the test you need.

The following code satisfies that requirement.

```cpp
[[gnu::noinline]] // Required for testing `this` == nullptr;else c++/clang optimizes away
static bool af_isnullptr(void* self) { return self == nullptr; }
```

In your `class` or `struct` you can then use it as follows:

```cpp
class Example {
  void member() {
    if(af_isnullptr(this)) {
      // handle `this == nullptr` case
    }
  }
};
```

#### See also:

- [C++ Core Guidelines *comments*](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#user-content-ri-nullptr)
- [`[[gsl::not_null]]` attribute](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL#user-content-microsoft-gsl-implements-the-following-from-the-c-core-guidelines) intentions.
- [`[[gsl::strict_not_null]]` attribute](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL#user-content-the-following-features-do-not-exist-in-or-have-been-removed-from-the-c-core-guidelines) intentions.

Comment: I find it ironic that the only way to achieve necessary semantics is to force the generation of needlessly inefficient code.

Comment: Lol, fully agree with you. But is not as bad as it might look examining the generated code. There are other less portable techniques using inline-assembly/GAS.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe if you try `assert(this != nullptr)` but I assume that will complain as well. You may want to try and typecast `this` and then check that value:

```
int* ptr = static_cast<int*>(this);
```

Then check with `assert`.

Comment: A `static_cast` to `int*` shouldn't compile, and a `reinterpret_cast` to `int*` doesn't handle the OP's valid concern that the result might not be `nullptr` even when the original pointer was.

Answer (score -3):

`clang` is right with warning you - If the condition `this == 0` evaluates to true, your program has already gone south and is exposing undefined behavior. So you are expecting *defined* behavior (proper execution of `assert()`) when you already know your program **cannot** be expected to behave, which is kind of odd.

Sounds like hanging on a rope that you try to cut above you and knot the ends together again...

If you want to make sure your method is not called accidentally with `(this == 0)`, simply make it `virtual` and it will forcibly dump core.

Comment: This mocks the OP for having asked the question and doesn't even try to answer it. That would've been pointlessly rude even without the swearing.

Comment: While you are right that this is undefined behavior according to the standard (which I know), in practice this does not cause the famous nasal demons. Rather, the major compilers (gcc, clang, msvc) on x86/x64 have reproducible behavior, and to the obvious thing (calling the method with `this` = null). There is a lot of existing code that relies on this fact, including MFC.

Comment: @jdm Even(?) if you tell me "MFC uses it" - It's still wrong. And relying on some implementation-specific luck with the compiler you use is not what I call safe software. As soon as you try to do this with a virtual function, your code will almost certainly crash.

Comment: The question is not whether this is "right" or "wrong" - I don't *want* to call a method through a null pointer. But it happens in my code base, and I want to detect it, to get rid of it. For various reasons, I'd like to detect it on the method side (not on the caller side using e.g. -fsanitize). The reason I believe this is possible is that all the compilers I care about (in fact every compiler I've seen) have the same specific behavior.

Comment: @jdm I am wondering why on the one hand you want to get rid of a *warning* for something that you apparently *know is wrong*. If you can live with code that is definitely wrong (but works for you), why can't you live with the warning, then?

Comment: @tofro: The main problem is not the UB when calling a method on a null pointer, the problem is what happens inside of the method! My code of course assumes `this != 0`. It calls further methods on `this`, maybe passes it as an argument to other functions - and then somewhere in my code, a pointer that should never be zero is dereferenced and my code crashes.

Comment: I can live with calling the method on null *because I have no other choice* - the bug is already there, I can't just choose to make no mistakes :-). I'm not doing this on purpose. Now, I find it not morally wrong to use implementation-defined behavior to detect undefined behavior.

Comment: @tofro: The behavior was *defined* in many C++ implementations prior to the publication of the first standards, and the Standard allowed implementations to continue supporting the behavior in cases where their customers would find it useful.  If the first standards had been recognized as implying that compilers should be expected to break such code without providing any option to process it meaningfully, the Standard would have been soundly rejected.

Comment: @supercat I think the better choice would have been to break existing code (and force programmers to make that method `static`in existing programs) than to have code break for no obvious reason other than adding access to a member variable. But, well, opinions....

Comment: @tofro: The right choice would have been to have a method declaration syntax which would indicate that an expression `foo->bar(boz, baz);` should be treated as syntactic sugar for `fooType::bar(foo, boz, baz);` without regard for whether `foo` is null, since the ability to have the type of `*foo` imply that `bar` means `fooType::bar` would be useful whether or not `foo` held a pointer to an instance of that type.  Unfortunately, both the C and C++ standards tended to handle situations where some implementations would process a construct usefully and others wouldn't by writing rules that...

Comment: ...compilers would be free to ignore in cases where they would make the language less useful.  If there had been any intention that the rules be followed religiously, the authors of the Standard would have spent more care ensuring that the rules either accommodated, or provided practical replacements for, all pre-existing constructs that programmers found useful.  Unfortunately, the way the Standard has been interpreted since then has resulted in useful constructs being removed without any practical replacement.